# iOS Saving Media Picker Selections

Tags: iphone, ios, media, picker

I am trying to create an app that saves the user's media selections from a Media Picker to be reused and avoid having to re-pick the items . Is there a way to do this with the Media Picker or any example code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to save the media selection in the app's sandbox i.e. Documents directory for re-use. Because, you can't access the media without user intervention i.e. you've to present media picker each time whenever you wanna pick something from the gallery. You can use something like this to save an image in app's doc directory:

```
+(BOOL)saveImageInDocumentsDirectory:(UIImage*)image WithName:(NSString*)name {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        return [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

And to retrieve the images:

```
+(UIImage*)getImageFromDocumentsDirectoryWithName:(NSString*)name {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    return [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] autorelease];
}
```

Hope it'll be helpful.